# Исключение маленьких участков закращеных пикселей с изображения

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, aforge

Допустим существует изображение состоящее с линий. На нём так же есть небольшие "точки" которые состоят из малого количества пикселей. Есть ли возможность обработать все "участки" белых пикселей, который состоят из меньшего количества пикселей чем указано?
Пример
Оригинальное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат который я хочу получить(убраны маленькие клочки белых пикселей):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я работаю в C# с библиотекой AForge. Советы касающееся C++ так же приветствуются. Подсказка, как такой функционал называется так же будут очень полезными.

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов как убрать точки размером в 1-2 px, в любом случае это не относится к компьютерному зрению. Первый вычисление оттенка и соседних пикселей, прогнав через цикл, заменой оттенком соседнего пикселя.

Comment: @DigitalCore я было наткнулся на такой ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262600/how-to-detect-region-of-large-of-white-pixels-using-opencv и предположил, что есть уже готовое решение для C# или C++

Comment: несомненно при помощи AForge можно достичь результата используя фильтры, если найду старый проект дам примеры использования.

Comment: @DigitalCore Я не мог даже найти название данной методики. Поискав немного, я нашёл. А параллельно нашёл и фильтры в AForge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой функционал называется **Opening Area**. Это помогло мне найти нужное решение. В данном случае, это класс **[BlobsFiltering](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4a83d944-d776-ba2c-9847-3254fe3dbfdd.htm)**  в библиотеке **AForge**